# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 30" Monitor

Tags: visual-studio-2008, monitor

Visual Studio 2008 SP1 runs really slow on my 30" Monitor, is anyone else having this issue or have a fix for this?  What I mean by runs slow, is when I scroll or start typing something, it takes a little while for it to respond.  When I put it on my smaller monitor (24" or smaller) it works perfect.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This has most definitely nothing to do with your monitor size, probably not your monitor at all. If you have two monitors on the same system, and one is slow, then check the graphics card driver for that monitor (provided you have two graphics cards).

Comment: Well since they are running off the same graphics card, that doesn't really make sense, and the graphics card is a 512mb Radeon 4600 HD, and it can support 2 30" monitors without an issue.  1 thing i noticed is that my cpu uses around 20% when Visual Studio is on the 30" monitor and barely any when it's on the smaller one.

Comment: Wow, that's really, really odd. What resolutions do you have on the two monitors?

Comment: The 30" is 2560x1600 and the other one is a 24" and it's at 1920x1200.  At first I thought it was the same issue that seems like a lot of people are having with VS '08, with validation, but it works fine on my smaller monitors, and it doesn't do anything whether I turn validation on or off.

Comment: This explaination does make sense. Some graphics cards accelerate the primary monitor but not the secondary. Try switching the two monitors - try making the other monitor primary and try swapping the video plugins.

Comment: Seconded. You could additionally try giving both monitors the same resolution.